# UpdatePanel and Timer not working

Tags: asp.net, timer, updatepanel, asp.net-4.5, updateprogress

I have this code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="TickEvent"></asp:Timer>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <img src="http://jimpunk.net/Loading/wp-content/uploads/loading18.gif" />
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

Codebehind code:

```
protected void TickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

But when I run the page, the time doesn't update and the progresspanel doesn't show. Can any one help?

Comment: actually it does work for me with exactly the same code, it shows the loading image and updating time, check maybe there are other elements in the page preventing it from working.

Comment: @BlackBaron Thank you, but the code that I posted is all the code in the page.

Comment: hmm that's weird because it is working with me, are you sure you registered ajaxtoolkit correctly?in the web config and in the page?

Comment: @BlackBaron, can you tell me how to reference ajaxtoolkit in web.config for ASP.net v4.5

Comment: put this under <pages><controls><add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />

Comment: I get this errors in the Firebug console:
GET http://localhost:51154/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:51154/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:51154/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught Error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load
Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined

Can you recognize what's the problem?

Comment: @BlackBaron Now it's working and I found what's missing, I was missing some script files from the Scripts folder

Comment: ah great glad you solved the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by recopying all the scripts files to Scripts folder